# SSAS "MSOLAP100" Connection manager

Tags: ssis, ssas

I have an SSIS package that processes a cube via the "Analysis Services Processing Task".

I have a connection string as follows:

```
Data Source=<SERVER NAME>;Initial Catalog=<CATALOG NAME>;Provider=MSOLAP.5;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

The packages are stored on an SSIS Server and are executed via a windows work flow which will pass the Data Source, Initial Catalog, User ID as well as Password to the Connection Manager as parameters.

[image: SSIS Package Configuration of Connection Managers]

I have tested the connection to the Cube on SSDT and it seems to work. However when I execute the package via the workflow or directly from the SSIS Server it does not seem to find the connection. I get the following error:

[image: SSIS Server Error message]

According to [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141018(v=sql.110).aspx) you can only connect to a " You can only connect to an Analysis Services project while developing packages in SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT)."

Has anyone ran into this issue before and is there a work around?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And the next part of that quote is `At run time, packages connect to the server and the database to which you deployed the Analysis Services project`

Comment: Ok so that means then it should work. But for some reason it does not like it when I pass in the credentials as parameters.

Comment: You're saying that a User ID and Password is passed to the connection manager but at the same time you're using Integrated Security. If you're using Integrated Security then perhaps the account which is exucuting the SSIS package (SQL Server Agent service account?) doesn't have the correct permissions?

Comment: I have tried using Credentials as well:

Data Source=<Data Source>;Database=<Databse>;Provider=Provider=MSOLAP.5;User ID=<UserID>;

Password=<Password>;

But this does not work either. But it does work in SSDT.

Comment: @JodyT I agree. Check the SQL Agent service account permissions in SSAS or use a proxy in your SQL Agent job to run as other stored windows credentials. Don't put the username and password in the connection string. That usually doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a permission issue. The credentials I was using had not been created on the SSAS server.